# Problems in proving that the projection on the quotient is an open map

Tags: general-topology

I consider $G\leq Hom(X)$, where $X$ is a topological space and $Hom(X)$ the groupof all homeomorphisms $f:X \rightarrow X$.

I have an equivalence relation on $X$:
$\;x \sim y\;$ iff $\;\exists \varphi \in G$ s.t. $\; \varphi(x)=y$.

I call $X/G$ the quotient space and I want to prove that the map $p:X \rightarrow X/G$ is open.

If $U$ is an open set of $X$ then I have that $p^{-1}(p(U)) = \cup_{g \in G} g(U)$ is open because union of open sets.

How can I say from this fact that $p$ is open? Why $p(U)$ should be open?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the topology on $X/G$?

Comment: @Pedro the quotient topology induced by $p$

Comment: Ahh ok...it follows from the definition of quotient topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open sets in the quotient topology induced by $p$ are the subsets $A\subseteq X/G$ such that $p^{-1}(A)$ is open set in $X$.

So when you proved that for any open set $U\subseteq X$, $p^{-1}(p(U))$ is open, you proved that $p(U)$ is open in $X/G$. And so, you prove that $p$ is open.